# Email alerts for comments on a pull request in Visual Studio Online

Tags: azure-devops, pull-request

In Visual Studio Online we've been able to setup notifications on pull requests and as a result now receive email alerts when one is created, updated and completed. However, no email alerts are sent out when a comment is made on a code change. Since we are using this as a forum for code reviews, the only way for the creator of a pull request to get notified is for the reviewer to add their comment *and* set their response to Rejected.

Is there any way to get alerted when a comment is made on a code change within a pull request?

Comment: If you're using this like an email system, why not just use email?

Comment: It's not just general comments that we want to be alerted on. The main use case is when a comment is made about a specific code change and appears beside the affected lines of code in VSO.

Comment: Just to be clear, I'm certain GitHub has this feature.